# Integration problem for multivariable

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

```
x = kr
ψ = x*Sqrt[π/(2*x)]*BesselJ[n + 1/2, x];
Q = 1/(I + 2*Z); 
G = I*Q*Exp[-I*Q*(r^2*(Sin[θ])^2)/w0^2]*
  Exp[-I*x*Cos[θ]]*(1 - (2*Q)/(k*w0^2)*r*Cos[θ])*ψ*
  LegendreP[1, n, Cos[θ]]*(Sin[θ])^2;
G1 = Sum[(2*n + 1)/(π*n*(n + 1))*(1/((-1)^n*I^(n - 1)))*G, {n, 1, 
   Infifnity}]
```

I want to integrate G1 first w.r.t. x from 0 to Infinity and then w.r.t. theta from 0 to pi.

```
Cp = Sum[((2*n + 1)/(n (n + 1)))*G1*s1 + ((n (n + 2))/(n + 1))*
      Re[G2*s2], {n, 1, Infinity}];
```

here, G2 is same as G1 but value of n change from n to n+1.s1 and s2 are constant number.

Can you please give me a suitable solution for that ASAP?? thank you

Comment: Please use the editing buttons available to format code.  It's not clear that you've actually run the code because of some spelling mistakes.  Are you getting no output or are there errors?  Giving such details will get you much quicker and more accurate help.  For example, you might want to check on your use of `n`.  You have `n` as a variable in the definition of $\psi$ and also as the index variable in the sum.

Comment: All terms in the sum for `G1` are zero for $n>1$.  Is that what you want?  You also use the term "integrate" but you show *Mathematica* code using `Sum`.  This doesn't make it easy to assist with this question.

Comment: i want to integrate G1 that is the bigest problm

Comment: there is no `x` in `G1` (since you eliminated `x` on the first line.)

Comment: i defined above that my x=k*r so i want to differentiate w.r.t. kr (d(kr))

Comment: means diff w.r.t.kr